# Unable To Publish On Google Play

Tags: google-play

I am publishing one of my game on google play (Slots). I am getting this email from google every time after uploading build on google play. Why I am getting this error?

Hello Google Play Developer,

> We rejected Lucky Vegas, with package name
>   vegaslucky.slotmachines.casino, for violating our Malicious Behavior
>   or User Data policy. If you submitted an update, the previous version
>   of your app is still available on Google Play.
>
> This app uses software that contains security vulnerabilities for
>   users or allows the collection of user data without proper disclosure.
>
> Below is the list of issues and the corresponding APK versions that
>   were detected in your recent submission. Please upgrade your app(s) as
>   soon as possible and increment the version number of the upgraded APK.
>
> Vulnerability APK Version(s)  Deadline to fix SSL Error Handler For
>   more information on how to address WebView SSL Error Handler alerts,
>   please see this Google Help Center article.
>
> 1 To confirm you’ve upgraded correctly, submit the updated version of
>   your app to the Play Console and check back after five hours to make
>   sure the warning is gone.
>
> While these vulnerabilities may not affect every app that uses this
>   software, it’s best to stay up to date on all security patches. Make
>   sure to update any libraries in your app that have known security
>   issues, even if you're not sure the issues are relevant to your app.
>
> Apps must also comply with the Developer Distribution Agreement and
>   Developer Program Policies.
>
> If you feel we have made this determination in error, please reach out
>   to our developer support team.
>
> Best,
>
> The Google Play Team

Comment: There's a couple problems here. 1. you didn't actually ask a question. 2. If Google rejected your app and it's unclear why, we can't guess what the problem is. You need to contact Google to get it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is here

"Vulnerability APK Version(s) Deadline to fix SSL Error Handler For more information on how to address WebView SSL Error Handler alerts, please see this Google Help Center article."

I am guessing on your webview you don't handle SSL error but you just proceed if an error occurs.

Correct that and you should be able to submit.

Comment: I am not any kind of webview even I removed all the SDK to test.

Comment: Go to your alerts page on your play store console and it should show you specifically which file contains the error.